# Checked type-cast in an Expression Tree?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am using Expression to create a little bit of dynamically-generated code. My solution works, except for one feature: I want to do a checked type-cast, where TypeCastException is thrown if the cast fails.

I have found Expression.TypeAs(), which does the type conversion, but it returns null, rather than throwing, when the cast fails.

Is there a simple way to do a checked type-cast in Expression? Or do I have to check for null and throw the exception myself?

Here's what I have: -

```
ParameterExpression typedAttribute = Expression.Variable(attributeType, "typedAttribute");
ParameterExpression typedValue = Expression.Variable(valueType, "typedValue");

BlockExpression methodBlock = Expression.Block(new[] { typedAttribute, typedValue }, new Expression[]
   {
       Expression.Assign(typedAttribute, Expression.TypeAs(attribute, attributeType)),
       Expression.Assign(typedValue, Expression.TypeAs(value, valueType)),
       Expression.Call(visitor, methodInfo, typedAttribute, typedValue),
       Expression.Assign(visited, Expression.Constant(true)),
   });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Expression.Convert` should act as a cast here.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I actually remember trying Expression.Convert() earlier, but I think I had another error in my code at that time, which prevented me seeing that it was the correct solution. Anyway, great to have a definitive answer so quick!

Comment: is there a faster cast? I'm creating compiled setters / getters but the boxing unboxing to object slows everything down..

Comment: @Demetris then: don't use boxed data... Hard to say more than that without context

Comment: @MarcGravell firstly, thank you for the input. so you are saying avoid valuetype to object or in general any-type to object? I need the generic "interface" of Func<object, object> and Action<object, object> - especially on cascading "elvis"-like calls..

Comment: @Demetris having a Func-object-object or similar, *and* working with value types,*and* avoiding boxing for maximum performance... you can't have all 3.

Comment: @MarcGravell ok - when I have time I'll make a member info holder of a Cast/Convert-less uncompiled version of the expression and join those on the next expression and do a final wrapping to Convert upon compiling the specific path as well as a type aware version avoiding the casting - thank you for clearing up my options so I can conclude :)