# Expression.Convert doesn't throw InvalidOperationException for invariant value type parameters?

Tags: c#, expression-trees, covariance, contravariance

[`Expression.Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx) generally throws in `InvalidOperationException` when *"No conversion operator is defined between expression.Type and type."*

The return type parameter of `Func<>` is covariant for reference types.

```
// This works.
Func<SomeType> a = () => new SomeType();
Func<object> b = a;
```

It [isn't covariant for value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx).

> Variance applies only to reference types; if you specify a value type for a variant type parameter, that type parameter is invariant for the resulting constructed type.

```
// This doesn't work!
Func<int> five = () => 5;
Func<object> fiveCovariant = five;
```

However, `Expression.Convert` believes it is possible.

```
Func<int> answer = () => 42;
Expression answerExpression = Expression.Constant( answer );
// No InvalidOperationException is thrown at this line.
Expression converted 
    = Expression.Convert( answerExpression, typeof( Func<object> ) );
```

No `InvalidOperationException` is thrown when calling `Expression.Convert`. The expression tree compiles correctly, but when I call the created delegate, I get an expected `InvalidCastException`.

1. Is this a bug? ([I reported it as a bug on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/698322/expression-convert-doesnt-always-throw-invalidoperationexception-when-conversion-isnt-possible).)
2. How to properly check whether a type can be converted to another type? [Some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6489845/590790) seem to refer to using `Convert`. I would very much prefer a method which doesn't have to use exception handling as logic.

---

It seems the entire variance logic isn't properly supported. It correctly complains about not being able to convert from `Func<SomeType>` to `Func<SomeOtherType>`, but it doesn't complain about converting from `Func<object>` to `Func<string>`.

Interestingly, once `SomeType` and `SomeOtherType` are in the same class hierarchy (`SomeOtherType` extends from `SomeType`), it never throws the exception. If they aren't, it does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

Yes. The expression tree library was probably not updated consistently throughout when we added covariance and contravariance. Sorry about that.

> I reported it as a bug on Microsoft Connect.

Thanks! Someone will have a look at it then.

> How to properly check whether a type can be converted to another type?

The question is vague. Given two type objects, do you want to know:

- Does the .NET runtime think the types are assignment compatible?
- Does the C# compiler think that there is an implicit conversion between the types?
- Does the C# compiler think that there is an explicit conversion between the types?

"int" and "short" for example are not assignment compatible by .NET rules. Int is explicitly convertible but not implicitly convertible to short, and short is both implicitly and explicitly convertible to int, by C# rules.

Comment: _"Given two type objects, do you want to know"_: As in the [msdn documentation on Expression.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx): _"No conversion operator is defined between expression.Type and type."_ Right now I have no way of knowing whether my expression tree represents valid code, until running it. For my purposes, I need to know whether an implicit conversion is possible.

Answer (score 1):

<s>It's not a bug.  Expression.Convert represents a run-time type check, so an InvalidCastException at run time would be the expected behavior.</s>

Edit: that's not entirely correct.  It doesn't exactly represent a run-time type check (Here's the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051.aspx).  However, the expression tree is created at run-time, so all the type checking must happen then.

Edit: I'm using .NET 4.0 too.

By the way, `Convert` doesn't complain about converting from `Func<object>` to `Func<string>` *because that conversion is sometimes legal*.  It is legal if the `Func<object>` is a covariant reference to an object whose runtime type is `Func<string>`.  Example:

```
Func<string> sFunc = () => "S";
Func<object> oFunc = sFunc;
Func<string> anotherSFunc = (Func<string>)oFunc;
```

Now, Convert decides whether to throw an InvalidOperationException by checking whether one type can be coerced to another.  When checking delegates for a potential reference conversion, it looks like the code does check contravariant (argument) parameters and throws an `InvalidOperationException` if any is a value type.  It doesn't seem to do that check for the covariant (return type) parameter.  So I am beginning to suspect that this *is* a bug, though I'm inclined to reserve judgment on that until I have a chance to look at the spec (see Eric Lippert's [Maybe there's something wrong with the universe, but probably not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx)), which I don't have time to do right now.

Comment: Exactly, so it would know it can't convert `Func<int>` to `Func<object>`? E.g. it knows it can't convert `Func<object>` to `Func<string>`. EDIT: So it seems it doesn't know that either. :O

Comment: @StevenJeuris Exactly.  The point is that whatever Convert knows, it can only know it at run time.  The compiler does not do the static analysis.  So you can call Convert with all manner of illegal conversions, and the calls will compile.  They will not fail until the code is run.

Comment: That's why I voted down, that's not true. Just try it out. Other SE questions actually refer to using the exception `Convert` throws as a way of checking whether a conversion to a given type would succeed. (Can't find it immediately, sorry.) Furthermore it seems to do even some form of type parameter checking of generic types, as `Func<SomeType>` to `Func<SomeOtherType>` isn't allowed as specified in my update.

Comment: @StevenJeuris your comment confuses me: `Func<string>` *is* convertible to `Func<object>`; `Func<object>` *is not* convertible to `Func<string>`.  Effecting each conversion through Expression.Convert, however, does compile.

Comment: please read it again. ;p P.s.: Maybe there is a difference in behavior based on .NET version? I am using .NET 4.0.

Comment: He's not asking for a compiler error; he's asking for an exception when compiling the _expression_ rather than running it.

Comment: Ok I understand your question a bit better now, I think.  Please read my (yet again) edited answer.

Comment: Relating to your update: (1) It's the intermediate convert step to `Func<object>` in your cast example which makes it work. (2) It does at least in one instance check covariance as well, see the `Func<SomeType>`, `Func<SomeOtherType>` example in my question. Don't get me wrong I really appreciate the effort you are putting into this, but your answer still isn't correct as far as I know.

Comment: I just found the following out. Interestingly, once `SomeType` and `SomeOtherType` are in the same object hierarchy, it _never_ throws the exception. If they aren't, it does.

Comment: @StevenJeuris First, with the `Func<string/object>` example: don't get confused between converting a `Func<string>` into a `Func<object>` and converting a `Func<string>` reference into a `Func<object>` reference.  In the code example in my answer, if you run it and examine the type of `oFunc` in the debugger, you'll see that its static type is `Func<object>` but its runtime type is `Func<string>`.  `ReferenceEquals(sFunc, oFunc)` will return true.

Comment: Second, the code that checks for reference conversions between generic delegate types should allow these conversions if the delegates variant type parameters are reference convertible.  The parameters are reference convertible if they're in the same object hierarcy, *but not if they are value types*.  It does the value-type check for contravariant parameters, and I am now inclined to agree with you that the code should check covariant parameters the same way it checks contravariant ones, but it doesn't.

Comment: Just did a quick check, it doesn't check contravariance either. Consider `Test2` extending from `Test`. Converting `Action<Test2>` to `Action<Test>` shouldn't work (not covariant, only contravariant), but it does (no `InvalidOperationException`). All that seems to matter is they extend from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Lippert answered part 1 of my question: it seems to be a bug. I started looking for a solution to question 2:

> How to properly check whether a type can be converted to another type?

I just commit a first attempt at a `Type.CanConvertTo( Type to )` method [to my library](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System/Reflection/Extensions/Extensions.Type.cs). (Sources are way too complex to post here, sorry.)

```
if ( fromType.CanConvertTo( toType ) )
{
    convertedExpression = Expression.Convert( expression, toType );
}
```

So far it supports checking **implicit conversions** for:

- Simple non-generic types.
- Variance for nested generic interfaces and delegates.
- Invariance for generic value type parameters.

It doesn't support:

- Type constraints.
- Custom implicit conversion operators.

It passes [all my tests for implicit conversions](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System.Tests/Reflection/Extensions/TypeExtensionsTest.cs). Although you can specify to include explicit conversions as well (and I actually [use it like that at the moment](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/master/Whathecode.System/DelegateHelper.cs)), I still need to write unit tests for all those scenarios.