# typeof gives exception 'Type expected` for unconstructed nested generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, typeof

Normally getting an unconstructed generic type is quite easy, using [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
Type genericType = typeof( Func<> );
```

I would expect the following to work as well, but it gives a compiler error `Type expected`.

```
Type genericNestedType = typeof( Func<Func<>> );
```

It's relatively easy to work around this by using `Func<Func<object>>` instead. However, where you 'consume' the type you then have to remember calling [`GetGenericTypeDefinition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx).

A scenario where you would want to 'fill up' all non-assigned generic type parameters wouldn't be possible. Again, it would be relatively easy to create a dummy type instead to indicate those parameters. (e.g. `Func<Func<ToReplace, object, int>>`)

Is there any reason why `typeof` doesn't work on nested generic unconstructed types?

Comment: Good question, I think it needs @Eric Lippert attention.

Comment: Just to note: gmcs behaves exactly the same as csc here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe this is a compiler bug - section 7.6.11 of the C# 4 spec (the `typeof` operator) doesn't seem to give any syntax which would lead it to be valid; `Func<Func<>>` is neither a valid *type* construction, nor a valid *unbound-type-name* construction.

As to *why* that's the case though: my guess is that it's very rarely needed (I've never even *thought* of using it before, nor heard anyone requesting it) and so the additional complexity  in language design, compiler implementation and testing has been considered to outweigh the benefit. This is often the case with "why doesn't C# have feature X" questions, as Eric Lippert is fond of pointing out :)

I was pleasantly surprised to see that it *is* possible to do at execution time:

```
Type unbound = typeof(Func<>);
Type partiallyBound = unbound.MakeGenericType(new[] { unbound });
Console.WriteLine(partiallyBound);
```

I was half expecting it to be invalid in the .NET type system, although I expect that could have caused other problems.

Comment: _"rarely needed"_, is a fair argument. I'm using it in a unit testing scenario where I want to reduce redundant code. I pass the incomplete type, and do tests on several types. If I'm not mistaken there might be some unit testing frameworks that actually already support this? Otherwise, it still isn't too difficult to write a custom `typeof` which supports this behavior myself. The main issue is, although it doesn't look like a bug, it's easily inferred that it would be supported, and seems counter intuitive that it isn't.

Comment: hehe - I *also* did the same quick test, half-expecting it to throw an exception ;p

Answer (score 0):

The main reason *I suspect* is simply that `typeof( Func<Func<>> )` wouldn't be very *useful*. It isn't a fully constructed type, so you can't **use** it for anything - and it also isn't a generic type definition, so you can't call `MakeGenericType(...)` to add the `T` to the outer type - it is the **inner** type that needs a `T`, so you'd need to do something like:

```
var closedType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(
    type.GetGenericTypeArguments().MakeGenericType(finalT)
);
```

So simply ... no real use in a `typeof(Func<Func<>>)` - it is *easier* to start from the ground-up.

Comment: I'm writing a `Type.CanConvertTo( Type to )` to resolve [a bug I recently reported](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7960018/590790). In order to test this, I need to properly test all coversions from/to value/reference covariant/contravariant nested generic types. I pass incomplete types to helper functions which construct all those tests. It might not be common, but it seems useful in my scenario.

Comment: When interested, I just commit [the unit test](https://github.com/Whathecode/Framework-Class-Library-Extension/blob/expression_trees_arithmetic/Whathecode.System.Tests/Reflection/Extensions/TypeExtensionsTest.cs). In `CanConvertToImplicitTest()`, near the end where I pass nested generic types you can see how it is used.